# Configure different settings per queue, not per address, in ActiveMQ Artemis broker.xml

Tags: activemq-artemis

We operate an ActiveMQ Artemis message broker to distribute incoming measurements (think weather stations) to downstream systems. There often are multiple consumers. So for example given the address `measurements.africa`, there would be multicast queues `consumer1.africa` and `consumer2.africa` attached.

Now some downstream systems are not reliable, they sometimes fail to attend to their queues. This requires manual intervention on our part to prevent the message broker from filling up. Since these unreliable systems should get messages on a best effort basis, I'd like to automate the culling of messages, when those queues start to fill up. At the same time, there are other queues that should reliably keep messages until downstream systems are available again.

So I'd thought to give the unreliable queues a common prefix, say `unreliable.` and then in `broker.xml` configure those queues to drop messages:

```xml
<address-setting match="reliable.#">
   <expiry-delay>-1</expiry-delay>
</address-setting>

<address-setting match="unreliable.#">
   <expiry-delay>300000</expiry-delay>
   <expiry-address></expiry-address>
</address-setting>
```

However, I found that I can only configure settings on the address itself, not on the queues on this address. So the queues `reliable.consumer1.africa` and `unreliable.consumer2.africa` cannot have different settings configured in `broker.xml`. The queues are created automatically by the Apache Camel JMS component, using the `subscriptionName=` parameter.

I've read through [the Artemis manual on address settings](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-settings.html), but it doesn't mention a way. Is there a way to create queues with different settings on the same address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to apply address settings to a specific queue. In almost all circumstances if one setting is viable for one queue then it is viable for all the queues bound to that address.

However, in circumstances where you really need different address settings then you can [split the message flow using a non-exclusive divert](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/diverts.html#non-exclusive-divert) and another address, e.g.:

```xml
<diverts>
   <divert name="measurements.africa-divert">
      <address>measurements.africa</address>
      <forwarding-address>unreliable.measurements.africa</forwarding-address>
      <exclusive>false</exclusive>
   </divert>
</diverts>
<addresses>
   ...
   <address name="measurements.africa">
      <multicast/>
   </address>
   <address name="unreliable.measurements.africa">
      <multicast/>
   </address>
</addresses>
```

With this configuration any message sent to `measurements.africa` will *also* be sent to `unreliable.measurements.africa` which means that unreliable consumers can subscribe to `unreliable.measurements.africa` and reliable consumers can continue to use `measurements.africa`. Then you can apply your address settings like so:

```xml
<address-setting match="measurements.africa">
   <expiry-delay>-1</expiry-delay>
</address-setting>

<address-setting match="unreliable.#">
   <expiry-delay>300000</expiry-delay>
   <expiry-address></expiry-address>
</address-setting>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! I wasn't aware of diverts. It is not mentioned in the docs, but do they support wildcards? If I can do `<address>measurements.#</address>` that would work well for my case. I'll check this out.

Comment: No. Diverts do not support wildcards.

Comment: I had to generate the list of diverts into the config. But that works fine for me. Bonus is that there is now just one summary topic to listen to for the auxiliary clients (the unreliable ones) so they got simpler.